# Spring test: Avoid to load configuration class on test

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-test

This is a Spring `@Configuration` annotated class I'm using into my spring boot project:

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ 
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/web/rs/config/canigo-web-rs.xml",
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/core/i18n/config/canigo-core-i18n.xml"
})
public class WebServicesConfiguration {
```

As you can see I'm importing third-party declared resources.

Nevertheless, I'm trying to avoid to import them into my tests. Currently, I'm trying to create tests in order to test database communication. I don't need to load those resources.

How could I get it?

Here's my related code snippet:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest()
public class ModelTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
```

So, I want to avoid to load `WebServicesConfiguration` configuration class when `ModelTest` runs.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why dont you use Spring Profiles?

Comment: Could you provide an example in answer, please?

Comment: What I want to get is to load only mongodb related properties. These properties are loaded by `spring-data-mongodb`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use **Spring Profiles** to implement your scenario.

First of all, add a profile annotation to your configurations. Note that you could add multiple profiles to a single configuration (as in the snipped below), and the configuration will be applied if **any** of the specified profiles is active.

```
@Configuration
@ImportResource({ 
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/web/rs/config/canigo-web-rs.xml",
    "classpath:cat/gencat/ctti/canigo/arch/core/i18n/config/canigo-core-i18n.xml"
})
@Profile(value = {"dev", "prod"})
public class WebServicesConfiguration {

}
```

Then, on your test side, define which profiles you want active for the test.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest() 
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = {"test"})
public class ModelTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a separate configuration for all tests and named it ApplicationTest. In your tests you need to specify it by using the following code:

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = ApplicationTest.class)
public class ModelTest {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
}
```